# Array and macro resetting

Tags: macros, arrays

I would like to make an array with some automatic calculations. I use the package `ftlpoint`.

I made a test, but it does not work:

```
\newcommand{\line}[2]{%
    \fpMul{\produit}{#1}{#2}% Calculation
    \produit&%print result
    \produit&print result in another cell
}
```

On the first cell, no problem, but in the second cell, LaTeX says the command `\produit` doesn't exist (undefined control sequence).

How can do this?

Ps. Of course, my example is very simplified. I would like to make other calculations as well.

Comment: You example is to simplified ;-) Please add a minimal working example.

Comment: You should use `\MyLine` instead of `\line` as I believe that is already defined elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, in fact, i work in french, so I use \ligne and not \line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to make the definition of `\produit` global. Otherwise it goes out of existence when you move into another table cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fltpoint}
\newcommand{\tline}[2]{%                                                        
    \fpMul{\temp}{#1}{#2}\global\edef\produit{\temp}% Calcul                    
    \produit&%seeing result                                                     
    \produit%seeing result on a other cell                                      
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\tline{2}{3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\global\edef` you could simply use `\xdef`.

Comment: the problem is that I have one value of produit by line. So I can't have an unique value

Comment: @Maieul --- That doesn't matter. `\edef` (or `\xdef` as @mhp suggests) will overwrite any old value that exists.

Comment: @lan Thompson : thank ! I did'nt know the \edef command :)

Comment: @Maieul: if this answers your question, you can select it.